# Regex: Match only if string A is found and string B is not

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will essentially return true if string A is found and string B is not found.

To be more specific, I'm looking for any file on my server which has the text 'base64_decode' in it, but not 'copyright'.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need regex for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure your real task can be solved purely within the regex passed into grep, since grep processes files line-by-line. I would use the `-l` (`--files-with-matches`) and `-L` (`--files-without-match`) options along with command substitution backticks, like so:

```
grep -L copyright `grep -l base64_decode *`
```

`grep -l base64_decode *` lists the names of all the files with "base64_decode" in them, and the backticks put that list on the command line after `grep -L copyright`, which searches those files and lists the subset of them that doesn't contain "copyright".

Answer (score 0):

Use negative lookahead and lookbehind:

`^(?<!.*copyright.*)(base64_decode)(?!.*copyright.*)$`

Perl doesn't support this yet :-P.

Comment: More to the point, grep doesn't support it. In fact, only two regex flavors I know of support unbounded, variable-length lookbehinds: .NET and JGSoft (or three if you count Java, but that's a bug :/ ). And even in those flavors you're usually better off using lookahead alone.

Comment: @Alan: regarding Java infinite lookbehind, I'd say if you know how to manipulate the bug to make it work for you, you can classify it as a hidden feature =)

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to do this in one regex, but if you must, you can use lookaheads:

```
^(?=.*must-have)(?!.*must-not-have)
```

You may want to do this in single-line/dot-all mode, and the beginning anchor may be `\A` instead of `^`.

`(?=…)` is *positive* lookahead; it asserts that a given pattern can be matched. `(?!…)` is *negative* lookahead; it asserts that a given pattern can *NOT* be matched.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [Dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

Comment: As far as I know, grep doesn't even support lookaheads.  But whatever the case, I agree that this is not the way to go.  Two piped grep calls are bound to be much faster than any Frankenregex. :D

Answer (score 0):

Piped greps should be able to achieve that easily:

find  -type f -print | xargs grep -l "base64_decode" | xargs grep -L "copyright"

Answer (score -3):

<s>i think it is</s>

```
^.*[^copyright].*base64_decode.*[^copyright].*$
```

however this will catch the phrase copyright anywhere even if it is not by itself in the word.

I was wrong, but bewhere that my example below still holds true for most other examples here

eg it will match

```
This text is non-copyrightable because I said so! but it is not encoded in base64_decode unfortunatly :(
```

Comment: Those are character classes.  Inverting them doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Tested it - only matches when both copyright and base64_decode are present. Needs to match if only base64_decode is found and not copyright.

Comment: @Borealid is right: you're way off base.  `[^copyright]` matches any **one** character, unless it's one of the characters in the word `copyright`.